# Files missing from a KDE vault encrypted folder

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, encryption, plasma

I have a single vault on my Kubuntu system, (fortunately not containing anything critical). As of yesterday this vault is empty, yet I have not deleted any of those files.

Is there any way I can find or recover the missing files, and is this a known bug with KDE vaults?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me today. I open my Vault, enter my password, and Dolphin pops up, but no files are within the folder… 
Although Dolphin did open, the Vault’s icon was missing the green plug on it. Therefore, I thought that the Vault did not mount correctly. I checked the vault storage location and it looked like the encrypted files are still over there. I created a new folder in my `Home/Vaults` directory. Then I amended the Mount Point in Configure Vault so it pointed to the new folder. This did the trick and now Vault opens with all the files within it.